# Aligning text in a table with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a really simple table with two rows and two columns.  I want the text in the first column to be right-aligned and the second column to be left-aligned.  I'm sure this is really easy but I just can't figure it out.

Here's the HTML:

```
<table>
 <tr><td>Previous:</td><td>Link 1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Next:</td><td>Link 2</td></tr>     
</table>
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use classes in this instance. You could get fancy but this is the best way for supporting.

CSS

```
.alignright { text-align: right; }
.alignleft { text-align: left; }
```

HTML

```
<td class="alignright"> </td>
<td class="alignleft"> </td>
```

You could go further by adding padding, margins and further classes. Depending on your TABLE css you might need to add some padding so that the cells aren't all padding: 0 and not showing any alignment.

Answer (score 4):

You can either use `:first-child` to target the cells in the first column:

```
td {
    text align: left;
}

td:first-child {
    text-align: right;
}
```

But [`:first-child`: doesn’t work in IE 6](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%3Afirst-child), so you might want to add a class to the cells in the first column, and use that instead:

```
<table>
 <tr><td class="first">Previous:</td><td>Link 1</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="first">Next:</td><td>Link 2</td></tr>     
</table>

td {
    text align: left;
}

td.first {
    text-align: right;
}
```

As written, this will apply to all `<td>` elements, so you might also want to add a class to your table and limit the styles to `<td>`s in that table:

```
<table class="simple">
 <tr><td class="first">Previous:</td><td>Link 1</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="first">Next:</td><td>Link 2</td></tr>     
</table>

table.simple td {
    text align: left;
}

table.simple td.first {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative and given your scenario and if you are able to - why don't you replace the `<td>`'s in your second column with `<th>`'s and then the CSS will be really simple:

```
td { text-align:right; }
th { text-align:left; }
```

Comment: Semantically, I think this is a bad idea since the second column is clearly not a header for anything. Trying to extend the header concept, maybe the first column could be considered such but definitively not the second one.

Answer (score 2):

set different classes on each td element

```
<style>
    td.raligned {text-align: right;} 
    td.leftaligned {text-align: left;} 
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="raligned">blah</td>
        <td class="leftaligned">blah</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. Create a class of CSS

```
<style>
.aleft {text-align: left;}
.aright {text-align: right;}
</style>
```

Now add the classes to your table, it's easy.

```
<table>
<tr><td class="aright">Previous:</td><td>Link 1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="aleft">Next:</td><td>Link 2</td></tr>     
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td class="right-align">Previous:</td>
     <td class="left-align">Link 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="right-align">Next:</td>
     <td class="left-align">Link 2</td>
   </tr>     
</table>​
```

And your stylesheet..

```
td.right-align {
    text-align: right;
}

td.left-align {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<col align=right>
```

inside the `<table>` element, to right-align the first column on IE, and

```
td:first-child { text-align: right; }
```

to do the same on more standards-conforming browsers.

Data cells (`td` elements) are left-aligned by default, so you need not do anything with the second column.

Answer (score -2):

Personally I would recommend not using tables and use a CSS solution that being said here's a jsfiddle option.  basically the same as other have said but with jsfiddle you can manipulate it and make changes so you can see them immediately.

http://jsfiddle.net/rhoenig/rnAVH/